# clear format in range

Tags: javascript, range, contenteditable

How clear format in selected text in contenteditable div?

I have range by `range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);`, so how can I clear format in all children of it?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try Document.execCommand('removeFormat') for modern browsers.

refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

> removeFormat
>
> Removes all formatting from the current selection.

Answer (score 1):

The following will replace the contents of the range with plain text, but if the whole range is contained within a single formatting element then this approach won't work and the problem is much harder. You'd need to get into splitting and cloning nodes at the range boundaries. Also, line breaks in the text originating from `<br>` and block elements are lost. So, the following would work for the following (range boundaries denoted by pipe characters):

```
<p>One |two <b>three</b> four| five</p>
```

... but not

```
<p>One <b>two |three| four</b> five</p>
```

Code:

```
function flattenRangeText(range) {
    var textNode = document.createTextNode( range.toString() );
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(textNode);
    range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
}
```